# using dropout wrapper equivalent to tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper in tf.keras.layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Here is the how `tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper` is used, using `GRUcell` for example:

```
        decoder_cell =tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden_size),
                                                    input_keep_prob=dropout_ph,
                                                    output_keep_prob=dropout_ph)
```

If we want to use `GRU` and `Dropout` in `tf.keras.layers`, and for the same input/output dropout procedure, should we use:

```
    decoder_output = GRU(hidden_size, dropout=1-dropout_ph, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)(self.ground_truth_embedded)
    dropout_layer = Dropout(1-dropout_ph)
```

The `dropout` argument in `GRU()` defines the dropout rate for input, and after that we add one more dropout layer for the output. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.

The dropout keyword argument in tf.keras.layers.GRU is dropout on the inputs, and the next Dropout layer is on the outputs.